# How to block countries from server when using cloudflare?

Tags: nginx, server, cloudflare

i tried to block countries nginx.conf with below codes:

```
   geoip_country /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;
    map $geoip_country_code $allow_visit {
       default yes;
      RU no;
   }
```

But im using CLoudFLare /cdn service.so when i block some countries.sometimes i cannot login to my system.Coz cloudflare servers maybe in my block countries.So i should remove cloudflare ips from block country list.But how can i do that?
any advice? 
im using ubuntu 14.04 / nginx on my server..

*

> and now im under the attack.You guys know, theres cyber war so i
>   should solve this problem fastly.

*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want help with CloudFlare's service, shouldn't you contact [CloudFlare support](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us)?

Comment: i think cloudFlare support really weak for free users.I tried to contact for support several times and didnt get any answer for my questions.Thank you for your helper answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

CloudFlare allows you to block certain countries from accessing your website at the CloudFlare level. To do so:

1. Select your domain in your CloudFlare Control Panel
2. Select the "Firewall" tab
3. On the "IP Firewall" tab, you can enter a IP, IP range, or **Country** and click block.

This will block the country from all your websites on the CloudFlare level, before any attack even hits your server.

If you require to block it with your Nginx solution rather than CloudFlare's firewall for whatever reason, you can look at enabling "IP Geolocation" under the "Network" tab of the Control Panel. This adds the header "HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY" to all requests, and will contain the Country Code (I.e US, UK, RU) in the header.

If you need to block any requests based off certain IPs, or perform the IP lookup yourself. Then you should use the default CloudFlare header that is included with every request that holds the client's IP named "CF-Connecting-IP". 
For future information, CloudFlare has a good [article](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170986-How-does-CloudFlare-handle-HTTP-Request-headers-) written here on how they handle their headers.

Comment: No. You can't block an entire country with cloudflare. Try it, the error says: "Countries can only be challenged or whitelisted (Code: 1212)"

Comment: $country_code = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"]; works though!!!

Comment: it is very inaccurate though.

Comment: Can this be done with the free version?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the free plan (cloudflare), you won't get the visitor IP address, so using geoip_country which matching IP <-> Country is not working.

You should turn on [IP Geolocation](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168236) in CloudFlare, and config nginx to read that country code.

Meanwhile, make sure your origin server only accept connection from [CloudFlare IP range](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/).

Details on how to config nginx: http://nginxlibrary.com/using-cloudflare-for-country-blocking/

Comment: I’m pretty sure all plans allow you to see the user’s actual IP address via Cloudflare’s extra HTTP headers. What makes you think the free plan is limited in this regard?

Comment: it is very random IP Geolocation